# Filter gyroscope's error from linear acceleration?

Tags: signal-processing, digital-filter, gyroscope

I need to use 3-axis angular velocity data for my application, but the gyroscope outputs angular velocity when under linear acceleration (not rotating). Is there a way to filter this error?

Comment: If you have translational accelerometers you can compensate.

Comment: Is there an equation?

Comment: One approach is to shake the gyro + accelerometers on a table and calibrate it out but I don’t know whether to expect a linear or some other relationship- maybe check the literature for your gyro technology (FOG, MEMS, ring laser etc)

Comment: You need to recalibrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's called an unwanted DC offset and all devices of any reasonable complication suffer from it. You get rid of it by either subtraction in the analogue realm or subtraction in the digital realm.

Comment: The sensor is calibrated, if that's what you mean.

Comment: You might need to "calibrate" out the imperfect XYZ orientation to fix this. This can be done numerically. Ask yourself - if there is a small Z value happening when Y is a big signal, how can you realign virtual axes to minimize this error.